# Android Large Image Rotation

Tags: android, image, rotation

I'm trying to rotate images taken with the camera of an Android device at around 5MP. Unfortunately it works only once. After that I get a "not enough memory" exception. Even though I release the former used image it looks like its data still occupy the internal image heap/storage and somehow prevent further rotation operations. Are any good ways known for how to handle this problem (e.g. free image memory, rotate images without needing twice the size in memory)?

Answer (score 1):

Making the camera give you an already rotated image:

```
    public void setCameraDisplayOrientation(int cameraId, android.hardware.Camera camera) {
        android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info = new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
        android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
        int rotation = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
        int degrees = 0;
        switch (rotation) {
        case Surface.ROTATION_0:
            degrees = 0;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_90:
            degrees = 90;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_180:
            degrees = 180;
            break;
        case Surface.ROTATION_270:
            degrees = 270;
            break;
        }

        int result;
        if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
            result = (info.orientation + degrees) % 360;
            result = (360 - result) % 360; // compensate the mirror
        } else { // back-facing
            result = (info.orientation - degrees + 360) % 360;
        }
        // set the right preview orientation
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(result);
        // make the camera output a rotated image
        Camera.Parameters cameraParameters = camera.getParameters();
        cameraParameters.setRotation(result);
        camera.setParameters(cameraParameters);
    }
```

Comment: Where do I get the value for cameraId?

Comment: _cameraId_ is a value from 0 to _getNumberOfCameras()_, see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#getNumberOfCameras() and the _Camera.open()_ function.

Answer (score 0):

How are you animating it?
Make sure you are using bitmap recycle.
Take a look at this article, it should be helpful:

http://mobi-solutions.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-if-you-want-to-create-and.html

Comment: Thank you for the article. I'm familiar with recycle and gc already, it does not work here. I isolated the problem so far now that it seems to occur after camera preview was in use.