# OutOfMemoryError: Android large Bitmap rotation (90°)

Tags: android, image-processing

I have a big Memory Problem:

```
// in sourceImage is a big JPEG previously loaded
Matrix mat = new Matrix();
mat.postRotate(90);
Bitmap rotatedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(sourceImage, 0, 0, sourceImage.getWidth(), sourceImage.getHeight(), mat, true);
```

Always i Run this code, my App crashes and says "VM won't let us allocate xxxxxx bytes"

Can you help me?

Edit:

I saw much similar questions here, but i don't know how to recycle the sourceImage before rotatating it... (cause the second instance is to big to hold it at the same time)

Thanks.

Comment: If your source image is large, it consumes already much of the available memory. After this operation you hold the image twice in memory (`sourceImage` and the rotated version `rotatedImage`). Which is likely to be too much. Please do a search for `OutOfMemoryException` on this site, this has been asked and answered many times.

Comment: Thanks für your comment, yes, i saw much similar Questions here, but i want to know how i can do this without holding two Bitmap instances in RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't create a new rotated bitmap without holding temporary 2 bitmaps in memory.

But you can display the bitmap rotated without creating a new bitmap (apply a transformation).

ImageView does not come with rotation capabilities, so you should write your own extended version of ImageView (RotatedImageView?).

The idea is to override the onDraw method with something like this (not tested).

```
@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {     
    canvas.rotate((int)(angle * 180 / Math.PI), getWidth() >> 1, getHeight() >> 1);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my Problem is, that i must have the rotated Image as a Bitmap, because i have to upload it to a remote Server. I also can't change the server-software to handle the rotation.

Comment: Ah well in that case there is little hope you can do this. Consider using a smaller bitmap or rotating the bitmap server side. If your bitmpa has the sale width and height you could write a very complex algo (with getPixel et setPixel) to rotate the bitmap on the same memory block but that would be very difficult to code and very slow to execute.

Comment: Okay, I think i'll export the rotation to the server's job. And I also think that the option with resizing the image, and using getpixel and setpixel should work, but as you told, that would take minutes to do this.

Answer (score 1):

For others like me:

there's an option to have the camera perform the rotation, 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16010289/755804